# django+nginx+uwsgi 404 on static files

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a django app, using nginx and uwsgi to serve it. My static files return a 404. I have set ownership of the files to correspond to the nginx username. The path to the static folder was copied directly from terminal, and I ran collectstatic (the static files are successfully served via the django development server). I have also run

```
chown -R username:username /home
```

and

```
chmod -R ug+r /home
```

I have tried both alias and root.

STATIC_ROOT is in my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user username;  
worker_processes 1;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

http {

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    # Configuration containing list of application servers
    upstream app_servers {

        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
        # server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        # ..
        # .

    }

    # Configuration for Nginx
    server {

        # Running port
        listen 80;

        # Settings to serve static files 
        location /static/  {

            # Example:
            # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
            alias /home/myapp/myapp/static/;

        }

        # Serve a static file (ex. favico)
        # outside /static directory
        location = /favico.ico  {

            root /app/favico.ico;

        }

        # Proxy connections to the application servers
        # app_servers
        location / {

            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the full path of your project?

Comment: /home/username/uswgi-tutorial/mysite

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to chown the `/home` directory to some user. That directory should belong to root. Change it back to what it was:

```
chown root:root /home
chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx /home
```

(The chmod you've run has probably not altered its permissions, but better be certain, therefore the second command above, which reverts it to what it was.)

You say that your project is under `/home/username`, but the nginx configuration says `/home/myapp`. Fix that. I assume it's `/home/username`. The `/home/username` needs some permissions to be fixed:

```
chmod o+rx /home/username
```

See also (my article) http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/.